# Odd exception thrown in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

Exception Thrown: "System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor is not marked as Serializable"

Does this mean I missed marking something as serializable myself, or is this something beyond my control?

Comment: As it turns out, it was a problem with Databinding.  I was able to eliminate it.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in your control.  Most likely the problem is the same as this:
http://www.codeplex.com/SharedCache/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=19759

Answer (score 4):

Can you give more context as to when this happens, and with which serializer? Most serializers have the ability to ignore certain members - `NonSerializedAttribute` for `BinaryFormatter`, `XmlIgnoreAttribute` for `XmlSerializer`, etc.

Having a `PropertyDescriptor` instance in your class usually means that your class is acting as a property-bag; in which case you may need to do custom serialization (`ISerializable`/`IXmlSerializable`). If the field is there for some other reason, just mark it to be ignored.

This (or similar symptoms) are also very common when you have an event (such as a change notification event / `INotifyPropertyChanged`) that the UI is hooked into (data binding); in this case, you need to mark the backing field as non-serialized. I don't know about VB, but with C# you can do this with "field-like events" as so:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler BarChanged;
```

Comment: *facepalm* Smashing my face against the screen wondering why `[NonSerialized] isn't working for my event. Missing the `field:`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a field of this type in your class.  If so, you will have to implement ISerializable yourself -- the automatic implementation requires that all of your fields are marked as Serializable.